# (Cleanly?) Consuming Messages in Spring Apache Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've put together a sample application to test out Spring Apache Kafka. I am having success consuming sending the messages through the [KafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html) and even able to output the messages being sent from the template using [ConsumerRecord](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html) so I know the consumer is receiving the data but I'm trying to figure out one thing.

**How can I consume the messages without having to throw some extra value in there when creating my consumerRecord bean?**

I'm wondering if I'm missing something where I wouldn't have to create this bean at all but in this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_even_quicker_with_spring_boot) I used I don't understand where ConsumerRecord is used in the `listen` method and where the method even gets used at all?

In my config class I have created a consumerRecord bean:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerRecord<String,String> consumerRecord(){
    return new ConsumerRecord<>("my-topic", 1, 1L, "key", "value");
}
```

with essentially dummy properties aside from the topic I specify being my-topic.

I am sending messages through the template to be consumed like so:

```
void sendMsg(){
    ProducerRecord<String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", "Sample Data");

    try {
        latch.await(1000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    template.send(producerRecord);
    listen(consumerRecord);
}
```

And I'm printing out all the values being sent to the topic to the logger with this method:

```
private static final String topicName = "my-topic";

@KafkaListener(topics = topicName)
private void listen(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord){
    logger.info("Consumer Record Value:::: " + consumerRecord.value());
    latch.countDown();
}
```

My concern is that I don't know what's happening with that "value" I put at the end of the consumer record bean. In a real world application I wouldn't want some random dummy value being consumed so how can I avoid this and just focus on the data being sent through the `KafkaTemplate`?

I used the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_even_quicker_with_spring_boot) as my point of reference when putting together the application (linked above earlier when referencing the guide).

*edit: If anyone knows?
 Can you pass the value straight from the producer? But surely it wouldn’t even go into Kafka then?

Comment: 1. ConsumerRecord Bean is of no use. Why would you want consumerRecord Bean. I agree you need ConsumerRecord class. but the bean declaration and creating of object inside it doesn't  make any sense. 2. In your producer code.  You are calling listen method. this again doesn't make sense. You should just send a record to kafka. And then Your listener will pick it up automatically

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks for responding, 1. can you suggest an alternative approach to the consumer record bean?
2. so how can I make use of the listen method then? I want to retrieve the data from kafka some how so I can make use of it!